# API with external generated session ID

Tags: php, json, api, session

I have an issue with an API I'm trying to call and the initialisation method.

The API requires;

Initialisation - Request a PHPSESSIONID from the API which is valid for 24 hours.

For every call you make, you generate a hash based on the session id, the call you make, and a API key.

Now, I got the initialisation working for one instance, but every time I refresh the page, I get a new PHPSessionID back from the API.

So in my thinking pattern I'd need;

1. Do initialisation only once - Save the returned SESSIONID
2. In every API call, generate hash based on SESSIONID
3. If API call fails due to invalid SESSIONID, redo step 1

Any help on how to set this kinda thing up? Getting lost here.

Comment: What sort of API is it? A RESTful api is stateless and shouldn't have a session at all.

Comment: I'm guessing its not a RESTful api in that case ;). I do have an URL with the documentation but it doesn't state anywhere 'what kind'.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the full details of your application or the API it is a little hard to answer.

RESTful api's are stateless and shouldn't have a session, if this particular API creates a session for 24 hours, then I guess it comes down to how your application works.

If you only want to know about the API session while your user has a session on your application, then you could store the API's PHPSESSIONID (or the hash) in the users session so that you can use it until the session expires.